# NodeJS synchronous code

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization, promise, q

I have a server written in NodeJS.
I would like to execute some IO code (querying a remote table) and hold EVERYTHING until the table data is fully processed.

ATM, this IO code is being executed and returns a promise for results.
My problem right now is that the rest of the code is being executed, and some of it depends on objects that cannot be constructed until the IO code has finished.

I cannot put the rest of the code in a "then" clause of that promise because it's a lot of code and I don't think it's the elegant way for solving that problem.

I know that NodeJS programs should not block the running because of IO operations, but because this only happens when the server starts up I can tolerate this, the question is how.

So the question is, if I have this code:

```
function() {
    var usefulObject;

    var promise = resultOfTableQuery();
    promise.then(result => {
        usefulObject = new usefulObject(result);
    });

    // very long code ...

    app.get('/application/main', 
        (req, req, next) => {
            // bla bla
        },
        usefulObject
    );
}
```

How can I NOT execute the rest of the **very long code** until the promise has been settled? (without wrapping it in a "then" clause).

Comment: well, you can just wrap the long code in a function and execute it right after the data in the table was processed

Comment: The whole point of Node.js is that you can't do that.  Use promises.

Comment: @SLaks I'm looking for something like C#'s 'await'.

Comment: that's the *fun* of asynchronous code, you have to *think* asynchronously

Comment: Put the rest of the code in a function and call that function in the `.then()` handler.  Welcome to asynchronous programming.  This IS how you do it.  You CAN'T magically wish an async operation to somehow behave synchronous.  The async result is not available until the callback is called or promise is resolved so THAT is where you process the result and put any code that uses the result.  This IS the elegant way to solve your problem.  You need to stop resisting the proper and only way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

What does your `long code` do? you can delay starting your server until you process the data from the table. Why are promises not an elegant solution in your eyes?

Well, since you don't want promises, you can just wrap things in a function:

```
function() {
    var usefulObject;

    var promise = resultOfTableQuery();
    promise.then(result => {
        usefulObject = new usefulObject(result);
        runLongCode();
    });

    function runLongCode(){
        // very long code ...
    }

    // might want to define this after runLongCode finishes executing.
    app.get('/application/main', 
        (req, req, next) => {
            // bla bla
        },
        usefulObject
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should really avoid it. But if you really need it. You [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).
But in this case I don't think you should do it. The elegant way is to insert your long code into a different function. something like that:

```
function() {
var usefulObject;

var promise = resultOfTableQuery();
promise.then(result => {
    longCode();
    usefulObject = new usefulObject(result);
});
function longCode() {
// very long code ...
}
app.get('/application/main', 
    (req, req, next) => {
        // bla bla
    },
    usefulObject
);
```

}

Using async, it will look like this:

```
var data;
async.series([
    function(callback){
        usefulObject = new usefulObject(result);
    },
    function(callback){
            app.get('/application/main', 
                 (req, req, next) => {
                  // bla bla
                  },
                  usefulObject
             );
    },
]);
```

Comment: That's like his solution of putting the rest of the code in a `then` only worse and involving another library.